# Populating react-select options from flux store

Tags: reactjs, flux, react-select

My intention is to create a multi selection component using react-select. I'm not able to get around a small problem with react-select. I need the follwing stuff to be in the flux store.

1. The values already selected by the user. This is passed via the `valueArray` property
2. The values to be populated in the selection list. This is passed via the `options` property

When the user types something in the input box, this input value is captured using the `onInputChange` hook and this raises a flux action which updates the store with the new list of values to be populated and emits the `change` event. Now the problem is that when the `change` event is emitted, the component gets re-rendered with the selected values and the new set of options. When this happens, the value that the user was typing for filtering options gets lost(as the `valueArray`) gets re-rendered. Is there any way of retaining the filter text in react-select without moving the options fetching outside the flux store?

Answer (score 1):

Exist two places where you can store the state:
* In the state Component
* In the store

For this concrete case, you can save the selected values in the Component state and assign to ve value prop of react-select.

onChange func:

`this.setState({value: whatTheUserIsWritting});`

React Select Component:

`<Select value={this.state.value}/>`

With this solution if you rebuild the Component you will lost the state. In this cases you have to use external you flux store.